# express node server return a value to async client call

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Sorry, I tend to be a bad writer when I have not fully woken up, let me revise.

I am using expressjs with passportjs (local strategy) to manage my server and using connect-busboy to manage file uploading. I do not think passport will play a role in this.

Here is the server code for managing file uploads:

```
app.post('/upload', isLoggedIn, (req, res) => {
        if(req.busboy){
            req.pipe(req.busboy);
            req.busboy.on('file', (fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) => {
                if(mimetype.match(/^image\//)){
                    var root = path.join(__dirname, "../public/images/");
                    if(fs.existsSync(path.join(root, filename))){
                        var name = getUnique(path.join(root, filename));
                    } else {
                        var name = filename;
                    }
                    var ws = fs.createWriteStream(path.join(root, name), { flags: "a" });
                    file.pipe(ws);
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

As for my client page, it is used to change a JSON object which will get re-uploaded to the server as a configuration tool. When I upload a new image asynchronously I need to get the filename to update this JSON object while working on it. For uploading from the clients end I am using [dropzonejs](http://www.dropzonejs.com#installation), which did not require any configuration on my part to work.

So, in summary I upload a number of images via dropzone asynchronously, busboy and fs on my server save the file, and I would like to get the filename returned to my javascript to modify the existing JSON object.

**Edit solution:**

Thanks to Elliot Blackburn for pointing me in the right direction.

By calling:

```
ws.on('close', () => {
    res.send({filename: name});
});
```

after `file.pipe(ws);` to send the response back to the client. On the client side modify dropzone to handle the response like so:

```
dropzone.on('success', (file, res) => {
    console.log(res);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just send it in the normal http response. It'll depend what library you're using but most will allow you to trigger a normal req, res, next express call. From that you can access the file object, and return anything you want.

Something like:

```
req.send({filename: name}); // name is the filename var set earlier in the code.
```

Once you've finished editing the file and such, you can get the name and put it into that returned object and your client will receive that as object as the response which you can act upon.

Comment: Thanks, with this, and looking into the dropzone API, using dropzone.on('success', (file, res) => {console.log(res)} I was able to get the file name back. And it was res.send. will update post with solution.

Comment: @Drew fantastic, glad you found the answer